# Open a program and file at start-up to automate manual user process

Tags: windows, memory, automation

What I want is hard to describe accurately in the title so I will explain in more detail here.

I bought Crucial Ballistic RAM sticks and they come with RGB lighting. Crucial has software that you can use to set the RGB of each stick how you want them. The software allows you to save a custom profile file (.bxp) that you can save & open in the software and this will be applied to the RAM modules. However, It lacks the option to apply this run this persistently so every time your system restarts it goes back to the default profile and you have to open their software and load your custom profile.

I read some other programs can be used for a workaround where it will fix this problem and run your custom profile at start u but I still want to know how I could automate the actions needed to solve this problem in case it every arises in the future.

What is the best practice way to do this? Can you do this thorough a .bat file somehow? Is windows power automate perfect for this & the best way? I have some knowledge of coding but that is at a higher level where I'm creating software rather than manipulating third party software with no api. Can it be coded? is this best?

Hope you can advise me, thanks!

windows 11 system.

Comment: Does the Crucial software have a command line version? If yes, create a `.bat` file and place a link to it in `C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately

Comment: Before launching into development work for automating it, you could contact Crucial Support and ask them for a solution.